# Java - Draw rectangle with two rounded corners

Tags: java, graphics, rounded-corners

I need to draw a rectangle with the top-left and bottom-left corners, and another rectangle with the top-right and bottom-right corners, rounded.
I know you can draw a rounded rectangle using `Graphics2D#drawRoundRect`, but that rounds all four corners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this question haves an answer here  https://stackoverflow.com/a/20321954/4443053

Basically, you need to define your own `shape`. I-m pretty sure you can modify that example to your needed corners.